# JSF and JSP bean communication

Tags: jsp, jsf

Is there is any way through which we can store the value of JSF managed bean in simple bean to access in JSP page?

Answer (score 1):

Any bean that you add to page, request, session, or application scope is available to a JSP.  You just need a component on the server side, with access to the those scopes, to add it in for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the value from a JSF managed bean programmatically, you can use something like this:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();

ValueExpression ve = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(elContext, expresssion, Foo.class);
Foo foo = (Foo) ve.getValue(elContext);
```

Where expression is something like #{myBean.someValue}.

Now this foo can be stored in any other bean that can be stored in any scope, or foo could be directly stored in some scope.

Of course the code fragment shown above needs to be executed when still in a JSF context. If the JSP page is executed within a JSF context, you *could* also place the fragment on the JSP page as a scriptlet. This would be a very bad practice, but for some quick hack it might be a workaround.